# How to find differences between two arrays with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How to find differences between two arrays which have arrays nested inside?
I tried different approaches including filter but not succeeded.
We have two arrays:

```
var arr1 = [ [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6]];
var arr2 = [ [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 5]];
```

All I need is to get an array with elements which do not exist in the first array as a result: 
    [[1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 6]]

Comment: Show your best attempt. Did you read any of the questions about how to compare arrrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: If `arr2` had elements that did not exist in `arr1` would you want those as well? That is, are you looking for an element-wise `arr1 & !arr2`, or `arr1 ^ arr2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on `arr1` with the predicate there isn't [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) element in `arr2` where all items match.

```js
var arr1 = [ [1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6]];
var arr2 = [ [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 5]];

let filtered = arr1.filter(a => 
   !arr2.some(a2 => a.length === a2.length && a2.every((n, i) => n === a[i] ))
)

console.log(filtered)
```

You can make this more efficient at the expense of additional space if your lists are long enough to warrant it.

Comment: The complexity is O(n^3) with the nested looping. Probably better to create a Map ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai it really depends on the data. Creating and populating a map will be slower up until the point it's not and you will still need some way to test equality be comparing arrays or stringified versions of them.